# kahana - валидация на сайт

Tags: php, kohana

В kohana 3.3 не работает валидация на проверку сайта если он на кирилице, проверка не проходит , сайт считается недействительным. Можно но ли как то средствами фреймворка решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0):

Похоже ничего кроме латыни их валидатор не понимает.

https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Valid.php#L187

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Создайте баг на https://github.com/kohana/core и ждите пока починят.
2. Пишите и подключайте свой валидатор.